# Linux as a VMWare Player Guest - Audio Performance?

Tags: linux, audio, vmware, skype

I would like to be able to make phone calls in a Linux guest under VMWare Player.  At this point I have a Linux Mint (Olivia, Cinnamon) in which both Skype and Google Chat phone calls are choppy, inconsistent, and hard for the person I have called to hear.

Is there a distro I could use that's better-suited to this purpose?

Or - are there tuning tips someone can offer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've got the guest additions installed!

VMWare allows you to connect usb devices (that's also your internal laptop camera) directly to your vm.
The reason you'll want to use this is so you give the guest direct access to a microphone.
It should display your camera in the bottom right of your virtual machine screen, just right click to connect it directly to your vm (this means your host pc will no longer see it).